# Laravel Excel queue export not working, generate empty file with only heading

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using the maatwebsite/laravel-excel library to export some spreadsheets, I'm trying to use the queue feature of the library but it's not working. If I try to export without the queue it does actually store the file with the content, but with the queue it only exports a spreadsheet with the heading (and if I change the heading it keeps exporting the same old one, even after I cleared project cache and config cache).

Here's the code that create the job:

```
(new $class($filters, Auth::user()))->store(strtolower($model) . '_logs.xlsx');
```

And here's the Export Class:

```
class OperationExport implements WithHeadings, FromQuery, ShouldQueue, WithMapping
{
    use Exportable;

    public function __construct($filters, $user)
    {
        $this->filters = $filters;
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function map($data): array
    {
        return [
            $data->serial,
            $data->customer,
            $data->type,
            $data->operator,
            $data->question,
            $data->answer,
            $data->timestamp
        ];
    }

    public function failed(Throwable $exception): void
    {
        Handler::sendEmail($exception);
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Seriale WSK',
            'Cliente',
            'Tipo',
            'Operatore',
            'Domanda',
            'Risposta',
            'Data',
        ];
    }
    
    public function query()
    {
        $query = $this->getQuery();
        
        return $query;
    }

    public function getQuery()
    {
        ini_set('memory_limit', -1);

        $filters = $this->filters;
        
        $result = Operation::select(
            'operations.wsk_serial_number as serial',
            DB::raw('concat(c.company_code, \' - \', c.business_name) as customer'),
            'operations.type',
            DB::raw('concat(o.first_name, \' \', o.last_name) as operator'),
            'q.text as question',
            'operations.answer',
            DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(operations.timestamp, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as timestamp")
        )
        ->leftJoin('operators as o', 'o.id', '=', 'operations.operator_id')
        ->leftJoin('questions as q', 'q.id', '=', 'operations.question_id')
        ->leftJoin('companies as c', 'c.id', '=', 'operations.company_id');

        if ( !is_null($filters['company_id']) )
        {
            $result = $result->where('operations.company_id', $filters['company_id']);
        }

        if ( !is_null($filters['wsk_serial_number']) )
        {
            $result = $result->where('operations.wsk_serial_number', $filters['wsk_serial_number']);
        }

        if ( !is_null($filters['type']) )
        {
            $result = $result->where('operations.type', $filters['type']);
        }

        if ( !is_null($filters['timestamp']) )
        {
            if ( !is_null($filters['timestamp']['from']) )
            {
                $result = $result->where('operations.timestamp', '>=', $filters['timestamp']['from']);
            }

            if ( !is_null($filters['timestamp']['to']) )
            {
                $result = $result->where('operations.timestamp', '<=', $filters['timestamp']['to']);
            }
        }

        $result = $result->when(!$this->user->IsAdmin, function($query)
        {
            $customers = Company::where('parent_id', $this->user->company->id)->pluck('id')->toArray();

            return $query->where('operations.company_id', $this->user->company_id)
                            ->orWhereIn('operations.company_id', $customers);
        })
        ->withTrashed()
        ->orderBy('operations.timestamp', 'DESC');
        
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I get no errors, the file it's actually stored in the correct path, but it's just a spreadsheet with only the heading, no content. The job is created and processed but I see no query being executed.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Are able to solve this?